# Launch term in command-line-default-directory

Tags: buffers, term

Currently, I have following key binding defined in my `init.el`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-SPC")
                (lambda()
                    (interactive)
                    (term (getenv "SHELL"))))
```

As it is easy to see, it executes the `term` command with my default shell.

The terminal is open with `pwd` equal to `default-directory`, which by default corresponds to the directory of the file I'm currently editing.

What I would like to do is be able to open it in `command-line-default-directory`. That's, in the directory from which I launched Emacs. However, I don't want to change `default-directory` variable, because it's behavior is ok for me for any other purpose.

Comment: Have you tried setting `default-directory` temporarily with `let`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as DoMiNeLa10 suggested, let is the way to go. With a prefix arg, you can have it both ways, a default to the command-line-default-directory, and with a prefix to the local directory.

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-SPC")
                (lambda (local)
                  (interactive "P")
                  (message "local: %S" local)
                  (let ((default-directory (if local
                                               default-directory
                                             command-line-default-directory)))
                    (term (getenv "SHELL")))))
```

Comment: I would [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264339) using a named function instead of a lambda.